# Pasar a ORM una subconsulta en SQL Rails 5

Tags: base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails, sql, orm

Estoy tratando de pasar una subconsulta que me tomó 5 minutos o menos en *sql* a *ORM* (llevo más de 3 horas) y este no me arroja los datos esperados. Por favor si me pueden indicar.

Tengo una tabla *Adopción (`Adoption`)* que tiene una foránea en *Mascota (`Pet`)*, es decir una mascota tiene muchas adopciones y una adopción es de una mascota.

La consulta en sql no me costo mucho realizar sin embargo, como mencioné, la consola de rails no me esta arrojando los mismos datos que la BD, supongo yo que es por la mala estructuración de la consulta que estoy tratando de realizar.

Le dejo la consulta SQL.

```
select A.users_id, P.id from adoptions A, pets P where A.id = P.adoptions_id;
```

Los modelos

adoption.rb

```
class Adoption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, required: false
  belongs_to :pet, required: false
end
```

pet.rb

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :adoptions
end
```

Comment: estas intentando hacer un join de la tabla users y la tabla pets?

Comment: Si, pero que solo me muestre los dos datos pedidos en la consulta.

Comment: la cardinalidad es 1:N es decir un user puede tener muchas mascotas cierto?

Comment: Añadí los modelos para mejor comprension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías lograrlo utilizando el método `joins` y especificando las columnas con el método `select`:

```
adoptions = Adoption.select('users_id, pets.id').joins(:pet)
#=>  SELECT users_id, pets.id FROM `adoptions` INNER JOIN `pets` ON `pets`.`id` = `adoptions`.`pet_id`
```

Y podrías accesar a la información utilizando los nombres de las columnas; por ejemplo:

```
adoptions.each do |adoption|
  puts "User id: #{adoption.users_id}"
  puts "Pet id: #{adoption.id}"
end
```

Utilizando la consulta anterior harás tu código más eficiente al generar únicamente un query; aunque también podrías obtener la misma información con el siguiente código, el cual te generaría dos consultas pero, a diferencia de la opción anterior, tendrías disponibles todos los atributos de ambos modelos:

```
adoptions = Adoption.includes(:pet)
#=> SELECT `adoptions`.* FROM `adoptions`
#=> SELECT `pets`.* FROM `pets` WHERE `pets`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Y podrías accesar a la información aprovechando la relación que ya estableciste en los modelos; por ejemplo:

```
adoptions.each do |adoption|
  puts "User id: #{adoption.users_id}"
  puts "Pet id: #{adoption.pet.id}"
end
```

---

> Lo hice de esa manera, pero esta errado, ya que si te fijas en el
>   Query necesito en el where  `adoptions.id = pets.adoptions_id`, no
>   `pets.id = adoptions.pet_id` ya que no tengo la columna
>   `adoptions.pet_id`

Entonces debes cambiar las relaciones en tu modelo ya que la llave foránea debe estar en el modelo donde defines la relación `belongs_to`:

adoption.rb

```
class Adoption < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, required: false
 has_many :pets
end
```

pet.rb

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :adoption, required: false
end
```

Sin embargo, si consideramos la definición en tu pregunta:

> ... una mascota tiene muchas adopciones y una adopción es de una
>   mascota.

entonces la adopción es la que debería tener la llave foránea (i.e. `pet_id`).

---

Por último, si quieres utilizar el *query* tal como lo has generado, podrías hacerlo con el método `exec_query`, el cual te devuelve un objeto `ActiveRecord::Result` con el resultado:

```
adoptions = Adoption.connection.exec_query('select A.users_id, P.id from adoptions A, pets P where A.id = P.adoptions_id;')
```

Cada registro en el resultado es un *hash* cuyas llaves son el nombre (como *string*) de las columnas que resultan de la consulta; por ejemplo:

```
adoptions.each do |adoption|
  puts "User id: #{adoption['users_id']}"
  puts "Pet id: #{adoption['id']}"
end
```

Aún así deberías ajustar o eliminar las relaciones de tu modelo tal como las tienes actualmente, de lo contrario podrás tener errores en tu aplicación.

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera, pero esta errado, ya que si te fijas en el Query necesito en el where adoptions.id = pets.adoptions_id, no  `pets`.`id` = `adoptions`.`pet_id` ya que no tengo la columna adoptions.pet_id

Comment: @AdrianRama He actualizado la respuesta para aclarar tu comentario, espero esto te ayude.

Comment: si, entiendo tu respuesta, ahora basandonos en el aquery siguiendo con los modelos como actualmente estan como seria la consulta?? Y disculpa haber definido mi pregunta de esa manera.

Comment: @AdrianRama Cambia el `belongs_to` como está indicado en la segunda parte de la respuesta y utiliza el mismo código mostrado al inicio actualizando la relación`pet` a `pets`: `Adoption.select('users_id, pets.id').joins(:pets)`. Si no cambias la relación entonces tendrías que usar sql puro, e.g.: `Adoption.connection.execute('select A.users_id, P.id from adoptions A, pets P where A.id = P.adoptions_id;')`, pero aún así tus relaciones en el modelo estarían mal, por lo que deberías eliminarlas.

Comment: Seguí tu consejo y utlicé Adoption.connection.execute('select A.users_id, P.id from adoptions A, pets P where A.id = P.adoptions_id;') el detalle ahora esta en como lo puedo mostrar en una vista que se llame por ejemplo index.html.erb, teniendo en cuenta que guarde la consulta en un hash por lo que quedo como: @results = Adoption.connection.execute('select A.users_id, P.id from adoptions A, pets P where A.id = P.adoptions_id;').

Comment: @AdrianRama He actualizado la pregunta con un ejemplo de como utilizar sql directamente, espero te sirva.